# how does scope work when using property in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie question about scope: in the following example, how is `property` able to get access to `getx` and `setx` etc. That is, why don't those names have to be qualified with a `C.getx`, for example? The code is directly from the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value

    def delx(self):
        del self._x

    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

Update: based on comment

Conversely if I had a class like this

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")

    def bar(self):
        foo(self)
```

This would fail. Is that because CPython has no idea what's in `bar` until I actually try to run it (and at that point we are no longer in the class scope)?

Comment: Because upon class creation the code in the class body is run in its own scope. `getx`, `setx`, `delx` are simply functions defined in that scope.

Comment: understood - let me just edit the question to follow up on this comment to clarify things ...

Comment: Based on update: Yes, this class scope ceases to exist when the class is created. The metaclass (in this case `type`) will add the single objects defined in that scope to the class as attributes. This is why you need to prefix the class for attribute access `A.foo()`.

Comment: For a nice read on Python scoping rules see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471004).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is its own namespace until it is finalized, and so names inside it don't need to be qualified during class definition. (In fact, they can't be: the class doesn't yet have a name, so there is no way to specify the class as a namespace.)

```
class C:
    a = 0
    b = a + 1   # uses a from preceding line
```

In your class definition, `getx`, `setx`, and `delx` can be used unqualified because the `property(...)` call is executed during class definition.

After the class is finalized, the class has a name, and for methods that are called on instances, the instance has a name (traditionally `self`). Accessing attributes and methods at this point requires qualifying the name with either the class or instance reference (e.g. `C.foo` or `self.foo`).

Comment: Wow, such similar example : )

Comment: so it is the case that the interpreter simply never looks inside `bar` until it is called.. at that point the class is finalized and it's "creation" namespace is destroyed? if not, then why does `C.bar` not look at the parent scope as would happen with a nested function for example

Comment: Defining a function inside a class does not give the function any inherent knowledge of what class or instance it is defined in. A class is not a function's parent in a namespace sense. The namespace of a function isn't determined until runtime (which implies that methods of a class don't need to be defined in that class's definition).

Answer (score 0):

That is because there are two different scopes. One is `Class` and one is `function`.

When you define a function in a class, that function is defined in `Class` scope. You can build a minimal example:

```
class A:
    a = 1
    b = a + 1
    pass
```

You can see that when defining `b`, we can directly access variable `a` as they are in the same scope `A Class`.

But when you use a `Class` scope variable in a function, that is another scope `function`. So in this case you need to manually specify scope.

Actually, this behave varies from language to language.

Comment: right but if it's not in the current scope, won't CPython look in the parent scope (in this case being the class scope)? ie why is when `C.bar` is being defined, `foo` isn't searched for in `C` scope

Comment: @Alex A variable defined in `Class` scope is bound to `Class` but not instance, that means every instances of this class will share the same 
`Class` variables. But the variable used in methods is bound to instance. As far as I think, CPython **can** look in the parent scope, but that will be a little confuse as in runtime, a function in instance object need to look for variable in another object(Class object).